# How do I do a page break?

Tags: posts, theme-development, pages, content

Is there a way to add a page break into length pages?

Preferably automatically, but doesn't really matter. Ideally without a plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert the quicktag `<!--nextpage-->` into a post. Using [`wp_link_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) you can generate the pagination links.